# SEO consequences of CPanel adding separate domain as subdomain?

Tags: domains, subdomain, cpanel, multiple-domains

I've purchased a shared hosting. It has `domain1.example` as the main domain. Whenever I add another domain to this hosting say `domain2.example`. The CPanel system does create the record for `domain2.example`.

But it also creates a subdomain in my main domain (`domain1.example`) such as
`domain2.example.domain1.example.`

Will it affect the SEO for `domain1.example` or `domain2.example`. My concern is it tells the search engines that the site `domain2.example` is a part of `domain1.example`, which is not true as both `domain1.example` and `domain2.example` are two different domains.

Comment: This is one of the stupidest things that cPanel does in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't share/make links to this domain created by Cpanel, it won't be visible to anyone but you.

So Search Engine won't find it and it won't affect your SEO.

Comment: Search engines have a tendency to find subdirectories.  I would recommend additional steps such as redirects or canonical tags.

Comment: Also, add a robots.txt for each subdomain. That's the best way to control what you want SEs to access, in this case.